# SQL join on parameter list or null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I'm writing a stored procedure to select addresses. There are many selection parameters but what's causing me a problem is selecting states. 
The country is required and can have one or more country names. 
If the country is USA then the state can be NULL or one to many state codes. 
I have a table-valued function (ParmTable_String) so I can join to the parameter lists and this works when there are state codes:

```
DECLARE @Country AS varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @State AS varchar(256);
SET @Country = 'USA';
SET @State = 'ME, VT';
SELECT *
FROM Customer
JOIN ParmTable_String(@Country, ',') AS CT
ON Country = CT.str
JOIN ParmTable_String(@State, ',') AS ST
ON State = ST.str
```

but if `@State = null` I get a null result set. If I make that a left join and add a where clause it works for a single state code or null but not for a list.

```
WHERE State = @State OR @State IS NULL
```

Anyone have a solution to this?

OK I have a solution but I'm thinking that there's a better way as this seems a bit crude to me:

```
DECLARE @Country AS varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @State AS varchar(256);
SET @Country = 'USA';
SET @State = 'ME, VT';
SELECT *
FROM Customer
JOIN ParmTable_String(@Country, ',') AS CT
ON Country = CT.str
WHERE (State IN 
(SELECT str from lntw.ParmTable_String(@State, ',')) OR @State IS NULL)
```

Comment: yes and tried NULLIF on the string returned from table-valued function but no results.

Comment: Could you please post the code for ParmTable_String and an example of expected results?  I think I've got a good solution, but it's hard to know...

Comment: May be I'm missing something or wrong but to keep it simpler why can't you write 2 selects based on whether the '@State' is NULL or not ? One with join to the '@State' and another without the join? i.e use IF condition and write 2 separate Select queries. I'm sure there are much elegant solutions and this is crude but would work i believe.

Comment: @norla it's a bit long but I can post it if you want. It parses the first parm using the second, trims off whitespace and the parts are added to a temp table column 'str'.

Answer (score 0):

I am not not familiar with sql server but am wondering if something like this might work

```
State = NULLIF(@State,State)
```

** I am assuming NULLIF is something equivalent to oracles nvl() function

Comment: Thanks but the problem is @State could be 'ME, VT, MA, NH, CT' so that wouldn't handle multiple values

Answer (score 0):

NULLIF(ST.str, '') will return null if ST.str is empty string. Then you try to do on State = NULL, which will not return a record.

Try this, it should return the customer records  whether or not there are matching states:

```
DECLARE @Country AS varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @State AS varchar(256);
SET @Country = 'USA';
SET @State = 'ME, VT';

SELECT *
FROM Customer
    JOIN ParmTable_String(@Country, ',') AS CT
        ON Country = CT.str
    JOIN ParmTable_String(isnull(@State,''), ',') AS ST
        ON (State = ST.str or State is null)
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem with the left join option is the where clause as there can be many state codes. I haven't tried yet but I suppose I could add a select from the tabled-valued function in the where clause but I'm guessing I'm just missing something simpler.

Comment: Here's how you can filter on multiple states in the where clause with the left join:  `where isnull(state,'') in ('ca', 'ny', 'ak')`

Comment: Try getting familiar with the isnull() function. It'll help when you want to filter on a column but also keep rows where that column is null.

Comment: Thanks but I still don't see how I can use that. My state codes are in a stored procedure parameter like 'CA,NY,AK'.

Comment: Fixed my answer. Using inner join, with join condition that returns all rows where Customer.State is null, or the Customer.State has a value that matches one of the ones in the @State parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have an OR... why not try two queries instead:

```
IF @State is null
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM Customer
  JOIN ParmTable_String(@Country, ',') AS CT
  ON Country = CT.str
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM Customer
  JOIN ParmTable_String(@Country, ',') AS CT
  ON Country = CT.str
  JOIN ParmTable_String(@State, ',') AS ST
  ON State = ST.str 
END
```

Comment: As I've mentioned in the comment to the question, I'd recommend this approach for it's simplicity.

Comment: because I'm not so good at SQL? :) The real query is pretty complicated. There are 12 parameters about as many conditions in the where clause and a lot more to the select than a *. If I go the IF route do I have to dup everything except the @State logic? Is it faster without the OR? I thought of multiple procedures but that seemed more complicated.

Comment: It is true that no one wants to write 12(factorial) queries.  Here's the thing - when you create a single query where the parameters are evaluated *during query execution*, you remove the ability of the query optimizer to make good query plans for you.  It will make a single plan for the god-query - and that single plan may not be suitable for all parameter combinations.  To get around both of these problems (too many queries to write, single query gets single plan), most people use some kind of dynamic sql/ or machine'd query construction.  Build each query before it gets to the optimizer.

Comment: Thanks David. I have a monolithic procedure now but I'm finding that certain combinations of parameter values take too long to return to live with. Dynamic isn't an option for access reasons. I'm going to look at breaking it into a few procedures that might be called from one wrapper. If you have any suggestions for reading regarding this I'd love to see them.

Comment: For dynamic sql, you can't miss sommarskog: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: David, that's just what I need; I didn't really grok that meaning of dynamic SQL. If you want to add that as an answer you get my check.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
DECLARE @Country AS varchar(MAX);  
DECLARE @State AS varchar(256);  
SET @Country = 'USA';  
SET @State = 'ME, VT';  
SELECT *  
FROM Customer  
JOIN ParmTable_String(@Country, ',') AS CT  
ON Country = CT.str  
LEFT JOIN ParmTable_String(isNULL(@State,''), ',') AS ST  
ON State = ST.str
```

Comment: thanks, but with a left join I need a where clause or it doesn't filter on state and then I run into the problem of multiple states.

Comment: oh, sorry, of course, what you need is to modify the where clause. Basically, you're saying that when @state is not null you only want matching states, but when it is you want everything, right?

Comment: can't seem to figure out the comment interface.  In any case your where condition should read: WHERE ST.str is not NULL OR "@state" is null.  This will allow you to have a conditional Left/Full join as you intended